# Adding a manual dependency within Apache Netbeans 11 doesn't appear

Tags: apache, netbeans, netbeans-11

In the past with Netbeans 8 I would add a manual dependency by right clicking on the Dependencies>Add Dependency... When I do this in Apache Netbeans 11 the dependency doesn't appear which means I cannot right click on it and Manually install artifact.

I know the dependency I have entered has been added because when I open the project within Netbeans 8 my dependency I added in Apache Netbeans 11 is shown.

Am I going round this the wrong way? The dependency must be added manually as its a local project.

Comment: We are experiencing this same issue on Netbeans 11. We have to use mvn in a terminal to achieve this, it was such a convenient feature.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Netbeans 11, you have to go to your project tree and right click 'Libraries'. There you can add dependencies.

[image: Example]